# Pack and unpack in Perl

Tags: perl, pack, unpack

I confused with `pack` and `unpack` while writing a Perl script. What is the difference between between `pack` and `unpack` in Perl (explain with a simple example)?

Comment: pack packs, unpack unpacks its like printf and scanf

Comment: could you read the docs and mention what exactly it is you do not understand?

Comment: how to use this pack and unpack.I'm confused with both of them.can you explain with one simple examples.?

Comment: At the command prompt, type "perldoc -f pack", "perldoc -f unpack", and "perldoc perlpacktut".  Those documents present what pack and unpack do, and how they differ.  If you're still confused, you would then be able to come up with a more specific question.

Comment: @user3098497 - you really are going to have to read some documentation yourself and *try some code*. Otherwise this is going to be a slow and painful learning process for you.

Comment: The difference between `pack` and `unpack` should be pretty obvious from their names. Imagine you have lots of items of clothing and a suitcase. When you pack the suitcase, you take the individual items of clothing and put them into the suitcase. When you unpack the suitcase you take the items of clothing out of it. Similarly, `pack` takes a list of data items and packs them into a single piece of data and `unpack` takes a single piece of data and unpacks the individual data items stored in it. You probably need to be clearer about what you don't understand.

Comment: Have your read the [pack tutorial](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlpacktut.html)?

Answer (score 4):

Do you understand the difference between [`split`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html) and [`join`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/join.html)? [`unpack`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/unpack.html) is a bit like `split` (it takes a string and produces a list of values) and [`pack`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/pack.html) is a bit like `join` (it takes a list of values and produces a string.

Comment: I don't know about split and join

Comment: Well, you should probably get to grips with those before worrying about `pack` and `unpack`.

Answer (score 3):

`pack` takes a list of values and converts it into a string using the rules given by the template.

`unpack` takes a string and expands it out to a list of values using the rules given by the template.

```
$ perl -E 'say for unpack "H2H2", "56"'
35
36

$ perl -E 'say pack "H2H2", 35, 36'
56
```

Comment: In your example what is the template?

Comment: `"H2H2"` is the template.  You're going to need to look over the documentation.

Comment: instead of "H2H2",we can you use any other template?

Comment: Have you read the documentation yet?  `perldoc -f pack`, `perldoc -f unpack`, and `perldoc perlpacktut`.